# Use Bluetooth in Virtual Machine made using Virtualization.framework with Swift

Tags: swift, macos, virtualization

Is it possible to make bluetooth work on a virtual machine made using Virtualization.framework? I don't see anything related to bluetooth inside `VZVirtualMachineConfiguration`.

I'm running macOS Monterey 12.4 but building with the new Xcode 14 beta 1, so I have access to the new stuff that has been just announced.